# in powershell mvn install command

Tags: powershell, maven, command-line, jar

I encountered that mvn:install command which works well on the command-line interface in windows OS does not work in PowerShell interface.

```
c:\mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C\example.jar -DgroupId=com.libs -DartifactId=example -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Here is how you can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put an inverted comma(") before and after the -D tags.

here is an example from the command line

```
c:\mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\example.jar -DgroupId=com.libs -DartifactId=example -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

for Powershell

```
ps c:\mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=$path\example.jar" "-DgroupId=com.libs" "-DartifactId=example" "-Dversion=1.0.0" "-Dpackaging=jar"
```